# Best way to create a pdf with silverstripe 3.1?

Tags: php, pdf, silverstripe

I'd like to create a PDF File on the server side. What's the best way to do this?
Does anyone know a good solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a SilverStripe wrapper for DOMPDF, which should be just what you're after:

https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-dompdf

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need but I cant get it working.
I downloaded the module and dompdf from github. I put this http://pastie.org/9127946 into my Dataobject in the onBeforeWrite function. The Page Template is only to test it. When I try to save the Dataobject I receive an Server Error. What's wrong?

Comment: Any more info on the server error? Does your code work if you put it in the onAfterWrite function?

Comment: No more info sry. But If I put it in the onAfterWrite() function I receive an SSViewer Error. I solved this. But now the pdf doesn't contain the content. I think that's because of my page structure. I use Dataobjects for my Invoices and Offers which are shown with get Parameters ?id=Invoice123. I think I have to create a complete new template for the pdf?

Answer (score 6):

There is also silverstripe-tcpdf:

https://github.com/mparkhill/silverstripe-tcpdf

This module is also findable if you search for PDF on the addons site :-)

http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons?search=pdf

Answer (score 2):

I know that's an quite old question and already answered but I've also used Dompdf for a long time and it has a lot of limitations, like floating and css support.

Cause of that I wrote an module for wkhtmltopdf. Wkhtmltopdf uses a webkit render engine so that you'll have full css3 support.

If you want to have no limitations you could use [this module](https://github.com/creativeSynergy/silverstripe-wkhtmltopdf)

Small excerpt:

> **Create PDFs in SilverStripe with the power of WKhtmlTOpdf**
>
> This module adds the possibility to simply create PDFs from every
>   DataObject you have. Based on WKhtmlTOpdf and mikehaertl's php
>   wrapper.

Note this resource is too large to incorporate fully here.

Comment: Full disclosure: Your github account

Comment: @Drew yes, what's the problem with that? But to make it clearer, I changed the answer a bit.

Comment: Just linking to your own library (or utility) or someone else's is not a good answer. In fact it is considered Not An Answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a good answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)

Comment: See also [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: make sense now? Trying to keep your answer from getting deleted. Over and out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a TCPDF module...

https://github.com/mparkhill/silverstripe-tcpdf

Else just add TCPDF to your composer.json with...

```
"require": {
    ...
    "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.0.013",
    ...
},
```

and review it's many examples to get going...

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

or this one small snippet to render with a template...

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$vd = new ViewableData();
$str = $vd->customise(ArrayData::create(array('MyVariable'=>'MyValue')))->renderWith('MyTemplateName');
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $str, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$strContent = $pdf->Output(BASE_PATH.'/tmp/tmp.pdf', 'S');
```